# How to add or modify API data with Django

Tags: javascript, json, django

I want to know if there's a basic demonstration how to do the following with Django on the frontend:

```
TinyMCE (or form) -> JSON -> DATABASE
```

or

```
DATABASE -> JSON -> TinyMCE (or form)
```

Correct me if I'm wrong of the process above. I just thought it might be that way. But I'm not really sure.

I have a API setup and have Oauth2 etc and it works fine. But what I do not know is how to add or modify the content of it on the frontend?

For example I have the url `/dev/api/posts` and there's some output, I have not created a post yet though:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Vary: Accept

{
    "count": 0,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": []
}
```

I'm completely lost with JSON and all of that so any help understanding API with JSON and Django would be great!